# Android Studio で Flutter プラグインを追加しても Start a new Flutter project が表示されない

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Android StudioのPluginsでDartとFlutterをインストールしてRestartしたのですが、Start a new Flutter projectが表示されません。アンインストールしてダウンロードからやりなおしてみたのですが改善しません。
どなたか解決方法がわかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: android studioのバージョンを記載すると解決策が増えるかもしれません。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63153594/new-flutter-project-wizard-not-showing-on-android-studio-4-0-1 の内容は試されましたか？

Answer (score 0):

パスを通していないのではないでしょうか？？
自分のPCにFlutterの保存を教えてあげる必要があります

Macの場合：https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos
Winの場合：https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

あと

```
flutter doctor
```

の実行結果の
スクショを貼っていただけると、解決策が増えるかと思います